# How can I make multiple copies of an e-mail without cutting and pasting each time?

Tags: email

I want to send the same basic e-mail to 10 different people with minor changes to each one.  Presently I set up 10 e-mails and copy, cut and paste to the subject and information that will be consistent to all of them.  The subject and delayed send is always consistent to all 10 e-mails.  Is there a quicker way to copy the basic e-mail 10 times?

Comment: What software are you using? What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 1):

You can just open up the sent copy, and forward it multiple times, removing the "FW:" subject prefix and extra header info in the body to get it back to just what you originally typed.  I'm not sure if that's any less work though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Microsoft Office, you may want to read about mail merge.
I could describe the entire procedure here. But you can find much better tutorials with screenshots with a Google search. Mail merge is fairly useful but not widely known feature.

Comment: I don't personally see how this answer, well, answers the user's question.  What good is these random tutorials and screenshots on another website?

Comment: This is exactly what mail merge is for

Comment: Mail merge is a feature of Microsoft Office and Microsoft has a nice tutorial with images(http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-mail-merge-to-create-and-print-letters-and-other-documents-HA101857701.aspx) which I believe they will continue to host until the feature is part of MS Office. Explaining it all here would be tedious and unnecessarily long and still not as good as MS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would alternatively suggest using an email template.  Create a baseline containing the main parts of the message, save as template.

For instance Outlook.

> In the Save As dialog box, in the Save as type list, click Outlook
>   Template.

To send a message based on your template.

> On the Home tab, in the New group, click New Items, point to More
>   Items, and then Choose Form. In the Choose Form dialog box, in Look
>   In, click User Templates in File System.

Templates are stored in this folder by default.

```
c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates
```